# pyvips Image composite not working as expected

Tags: python, vips

When trying to composite images with pyvips 2.1.5:

```
import pyvips

i1 = pyvips.Image.black(100, 100, bands=4) + (255, 0, 0, 128)
i2 = pyvips.Image.black(10, 10, bands=4) + (0, 255, 0, 128)
i1.composite(i2, 'over').write_to_file('output.png')
```

It outputs green sq. of size 10x10px instead of expected 100x100px alpha-mixed sq.

[image: output.png]

Also compositing of multiple image files (`pyvips.Image.new_from_file`) seems to work OK, but doing so with one of the generated image above fails due to:

```
pyvips.error.Error: unable to call composite
composite: images do not have same numbers of bands
```

even if all images' `bands` return `4`.

Do I use it wrong?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `black() + (1, 2, 3, 4)` will make a four band image with `interpretation` set to `multiband`. This will be interpreted by `composite` as a monochrome image with three extra alpha channels (perhaps not the best guess).

You need to set the interpretation to sRGB. You don't need to set the `bands` on black to 4, it'll be upbanded automatically by the RHS of the `+`.

Try:

```
import pyvips

i1 = (pyvips.Image.black(100, 100) + (255, 0, 0, 128)).copy(interpretation="srgb")
i2 = (pyvips.Image.black(10, 10) + (0, 255, 0, 128)).copy(interpretation="srgb")
i1.composite(i2, 'over').write_to_file('output.png')
```

To make:

[image: result image]

The same trick should fix your problem with compositing black with image files.